# How do I chance the size of hotkeys_popup.show_help

Tags: lua, config, awesome-wm

My short key help is not tall enough to show all my shortcuts. Mod4 + s is the default binding to see the short cuts, when I use it I can see that the list is cut off and partially hidden. I am using AwesomeWm Version 4.3

Thanks for any help you may give

Answer (score 1):

I talked to Phycon on the Awesome IRC and he clued me in to how to modify the dimensions of a widget. The commented first line is the original, I added the next two and then used the "my_hotkeys_popup" variable in the place of the "hotkeys_popup" in the menu and command area and that solved the problem. I can now adjust the size to whatever I need.

```
--local hotkeys_popup = require("awful.hotkeys_popup").widget
local hotkeys = require("awful.hotkeys_popup");
local my_hotkeys_popup = hotkeys.widget.new({ width = 2400, height = 1200 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @jk121960, and the caveats mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/qll62c/problems_resizing_the_hotkeys_popup/), I've succeeded thus:

```lua
-- local hotkeys_popup = require("awful.hotkeys_popup")
local hotkeys_popup_jo = require("awful.hotkeys_popup");
local hotkeys_popup_jo_sized = hotkeys_popup_jo.widget.new({ width = 1000, height = 600 });
  -- for my Lenovo IdeaPad 120s 81A4
```

```lua
myawesomemenu = {
   --{ "hotkeys", function() hotkeys_popup.show_help(nil, awful.screen.focused()) end },
   { "hotkeys", function() hotkeys_popup_jo_sized:show_help(nil, awful.screen.focused()) end },
```

```lua
globalkeys = gears.table.join(
    -- awful.key({ modkey,           }, "s",      hotkeys_popup.show_help,
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "s", function() hotkeys_popup_jo_sized:show_help() end,
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72087412/9801909) provided by @joharr (but cant leave comments)

To change the text size provide `font` and `description_font` properties to the widget constructor, e.g.:

```lua
local my_hotkeys_widget = hotkeys_popup.widget.new({ font = 'Sans 18', description_font = 'Sans 14', width = 1920, height = 1080 })
```